# How to continue performing checks on a site if sqlmap found an issue on a URL of the same site while using --batch option?

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

I have a file `/tmp/urls` which has following URLs:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8081/?id=1
http://127.0.0.1:8081/?id2=1
```

I am using this command to perform checks on file URLs concurrently:

```
python3 sqlmap.py --threads=5 -m /tmp/urls --batch
```

Both of these URLs are vulnerable to SQL injection, but sqlmap stops after it found SQL injection on first URL.

```
[*] starting @ 14:36:53 /2020-09-21/

[14:36:53] [INFO] parsing multiple targets list from '/tmp/sql'
[14:36:53] [INFO] found a total of 2 targets
URL 1:
GET http://127.0.0.1:8081/?id=1
do you want to test this URL? [Y/n/q]
> Y
[14:36:53] [INFO] testing URL 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/?id=1'
[14:36:53] [INFO] resuming back-end DBMS 'sqlite' 
[14:36:53] [INFO] using '/root/.local/share/sqlmap/output/results-09212020_0236pm.csv' as the CSV results file in multiple targets mode
[14:36:53] [INFO] testing connection to the target URL
sqlmap resumed the following injection point(s) from stored session:
---
Parameter: id (GET)
    Type: boolean-based blind
    Title: AND boolean-based blind - WHERE or HAVING clause
    Payload: id=1 AND 2091=2091

    Type: time-based blind
    Title: SQLite > 2.0 AND time-based blind (heavy query)
    Payload: id=1 AND 9761=LIKE('ABCDEFG',UPPER(HEX(RANDOMBLOB(500000000/2))))

    Type: UNION query
    Title: Generic UNION query (NULL) - 2 columns
    Payload: id=1 UNION ALL SELECT NULL,'qzvpq'||'pzRoNRetqOkyhaPjPBWodibiZLLjkjWSuBqzkrsg'||'qqbbq'-- KgZz
---
do you want to exploit this SQL injection? [Y/n] Y
[14:36:53] [INFO] the back-end DBMS is SQLite
back-end DBMS: SQLite
SQL injection vulnerability has already been detected against '127.0.0.1'. Do you want to skip further tests involving it? [Y/n] Y
[14:36:53] [INFO] skipping 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/?id2=1'
[14:36:53] [INFO] you can find results of scanning in multiple targets mode inside the CSV file '/root/.local/share/sqlmap/output/results-09212020_0236pm.csv'

[*] ending @ 14:36:53 /2020-09-21/
```

Look at this line in above output:
`SQL injection vulnerability has already been detected against '127.0.0.1'. Do you want to skip further tests involving it? [Y/n] Y`

How do I make it `N` and force `sqlmap` to perform checks on every URL?
I know it should be possible with `--answers` flag, but what do I pass in that flag to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the source code suggests that it simply matches the word you used in your `answers` directive with the question it asks.

So, all you would need to do is something like `--answers "already=N"`, just like the help text for the command explains.